# Apache Flink StreamingFileSink making several HEAD requests while writing to S3 which causes ratelimiting

Tags: amazon-s3, hadoop, apache-flink, amazon-kinesis-analytics

I have an Apache Flink application that I have deployed on Kinesis Data analytics.

This application reads from Kafka and writes to S3. The S3 bucket structure it writes to is computed using a BucketAssigner.A stripped down version of the BucketAssigner [here](https://%20https://gist.github.com/vmohanan1/8d443a419cfeb4cb1a4284ecec48fe73)

The problem I have is, let us say we have to write to this directory structure: `s3://myBucket/folder1/folder2/folder3/myFile.json`

Before making the `PUT` request, it makes a the following `HEAD` requests:

- `HEAD /folder1`
- `HEAD /folder1/folder2`
- `HEAD /folder1/folder2/folder3/`

And then it makes the `PUT` request.

It is doing it for each and every request, which is causing S3 rate limiting and there by backpressure in my FLink application.

I found that someone had a similar issue with BucketingSink: https://lists.apache.org/thread/rbp2gdbxwdrk7zmvwhd2bw56mlwokpzz

The solution mentioned there was to switch to StreamingFileSink which is what I am doing .

Any ideas on how to fix this in StreamingFileSink?

My SinkConfig is as follows:

```
StreamingFileSink
  .forRowFormat(new Path(s3Bucket), new JsonEncoder<>())
  .withBucketAssigner(bucketAssigner)
  .withRollingPolicy(DefaultRollingPolicy.builder()
                .withRolloverInterval(60000)
                .build())
  .build()
```

The JsonEncoder takes the object and converts it to json and writes out bytes like [this](https://gist.github.com/vmohanan1/3ba3feeb6f22a5e34f9ac9bce20ca7bf)

I have described more details about how the whole pipeline works in this question if that helps in anyway: [Heavy back pressure and huge checkpoint size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71475768/heavy-back-pressure-and-huge-checkpoint-size)

Comment: Would you be able to test this with the FileSink from Flink? The StreamingFileSink in Flink has been deprecated.

Comment: I was running this on debug mode I could see there is a Hashmap that maintains active buckets. So the local file system always finds it in the hashmap. Potentially what is happening in my case when I run on s3 is that my cardinality is too high for this hashmap to handle?

Comment: Also I am on flink 1.13 since we are using AWS KDA to run Flink. What would be the alternative to StreamingFileSink?

Comment: That would be FileSink. See https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/connectors/datastream/file_sink/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Hadoop S3 file system tries to imitate a filesystem on top of S3. This means that:

- before writing a key it checks if the "parent directory" exists by checking for a key with the prefix up to the last "/"
- it creates empty marker files to mark the existence of such a parent directory
- all these "existence" requests are S3 HEAD requests which are both expensive and start to violate consistent read-after-create visibility

As a result, the Hadoop S3 file system has very high "create file" latency and it hits request rate limits very quickly (HEAD requests have very low request rate limits on S3). As a consequence, it's best to find ways to write to fewer distinct files.

You might also explore using [entropy injection](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/deployment/filesystems/s3/#entropy-injection-for-s3-file-systems). Entropy injection is happening at the file system level, so it should work with the FileSink. Except I'm not sure how it will interact with the partitioning/bucketing being done by the sink, so you may or may not find it useable in practice. If you try it, please report back!

Comment: Seems like Entropy is only for checkpoint data. I guess I am stuck between if I reduce cardinality, I will hit limits because of PUT and if I increase cardinality I will hit limits because of  HEAD

Comment: Entropy injection is happening at the file system level, so it should work with the FileSink. Except I'm not sure how it will interact with the partitioning/bucketing being done by the sink; you may or may not find it useable in practice. If you try it, please report back!

Comment: Sure, will do. For now I removed the sub-prefix that is the source of maximum cardinality and that seems to give a big boost in performance. Zero back pressure. Exploring this further to see when we hit put limits

Comment: We have fiddled with the bucket's prefix structure and have eliminated a couple of root prefixes to prevent them from getting hit with HEAD request from all the child prefixes and that has solved the issue for us. But I am really curious: Is there any plan to move away from Hadoop FS? Or am I alone on this bucket limits issue that it does not need such a step from the Flink community?

Comment: You could always ask on the user mailing list, but I don't recall any significant discussion about trying to improve on this.